# Loop in html table and check if a radio is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a javascript or jquery function that searches in a html table and if no radio is selected notify the user.I only have table id and don't know radio id(s).

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Comment: Do they all have the same name (i.e. they're all in the same group)?

Comment: yes i tried some jquerys that were not helpful and not clear

Comment: I am developing an asp.net prj and my radios are creared in runtime dynamically in a geridview and their name and id  are created by asp

Comment: As it seems to work... I want a Porsche !

Comment: Must... resist... urge... to... upvote Bartdude...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `is()` which returns a boolean:

```
if (!$('table :radio').is(':checked')) {
        alert('No Radio Button Selected');
    }
```

If at least one radio button is checked, this won't fired alert()

Comment: Thanks. Bus how about the case we have multi tables and want to search in a specific table using it's id?

Comment: then just use its ID as selector: `if (!$('#mytable :radio').is(':checked'))`

Answer (score 3):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/tYaS9/)

In the code you can replace `table` with `#tableID` so that code only runs for that table

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('table input[type=radio]:checked').length < 1) {
        alert('No Radio Button Selected');
    }
});
```

if you want to notify on `table` click

```
 $('table').click(function () {
        if ($('table input[type=radio]:checked').length < 1) {
            alert('No Radio Button Selected');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table input:radio:checked') will give the radios checked inside table with id `#table`
```